# Date attribute's length in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, date

The date attribute doesn't show the full value. is there a way to stretch the attribute size?

[image: here is an image of a record]

Comment: Don't edit your question to say "solved". If you want to mark any particular answer as solving your issue then click the check mark below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DATE` is a binary data-type that consists of 7-bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those components.

The issue you are seeing is that the client application you are using (which appears to be SQL*Plus) is choosing not to **display** the full components of the date and you need to fix how the client application **displays** the `DATE` value and (probably) not how you retrieve the value from the database.

SQL*Plus uses the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model for displaying `DATE`s.

You can either set the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

*Note: You would need to make sure that format model is applied in every session where you want that format.*

Or you can return a non-`DATE` data type such as a string formatted with your desired format model:

```sql
SELECT student_id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       TO_CHAR(date_of_birth, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS date_of_birth,
       major,
       phone,
       cogname
FROM   table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just suggest execute below SQL in advance in the same connection session:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
```

Comment: How do you need this is "the only thing he needs"? Maybe he wants to change this in one single query only or generally for every session he will use. Your solution will work as general setup for the current session, but not for the other options.

Comment: This is a very common solution for the existing connection.  And the caller can reset it to default value at any time. 
If you check some opensource lib implementation,  many of them customize the format after getting the connection.
but may be the description is not exact. I'll update it.